# How to make curve apply its bevel radius after all deformations

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have a wicker basket which is made up of curves. The object has a couple of array modifiers, a simple deform and a cast modifier to achieve its final shape.

[image: modifiers]
It looks fine from afar but upon closer inspection, the curve seems to be flattened. **Is there a way to make it fill the bevel only after all modifiers has been processed?**

The object on the right had to have its bevel depth reset to 0 before the  modifiers were applied; it was then converted to mesh and then back to a curve again before re-adding the bevel depth. With this method it successfully bevels the curve without any distortion to its profile. This is the desired effect I'm not able to reproduce using a non-destructive workflow.

[image]

Comment: Some modifiers have an option to apply effects on curve points rather than beveled geometry

Comment: Ah indeed. SimpleDeform and Cast has that, toggling them however has no visual difference over the final mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, Geometry Nodes can come tho the rescue. The Bevel on the curve can be generated *after* all other deformations, with this GN modifier at the  bottom of the stack, so is not deformed itself:

[image]

After various modifiers, the curve is considered a mesh by the system, despite never having been explicitly converted. So it has to be converted to a curve and back again.

Right: The curve with a native Bevel and various deforming modifiers. Left, the curve left un-bevelled, with the GN modifier at the bottom of the stack.

[image]

Comment: And it only took 4 years for an acceptable answer!

Comment: @ReyLeonardAmorato  I have an image of you with a long grey beard and fingerless gloves, brushing away some cobwebs, adjusting your bottle-bottom spectacles, fumbling in the bottom of a tattered, moth-eaten purse, for a green tick. Thank you!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing **resolution** under bevel in **curve** **data->geometry**.

Comment: @rey right one looks good why do you need bevel depth again. May be include project file for clear answer.

Comment: It actually is good enough for me, however I don't like the fact that it's not procedural. I like to avoid destructive modeling as much as possible, for greater flexibility with my models. With regards to your question, I had to reset the bevel depth to 0 before applying the modifiers and converting it to mesh and back to a curve to avoid the distortion.

Comment: Of course destructive modelling is best option for any modeller. I need to know exact process involved in that, from start to end. So I may need project file or more detailed images in each every step to answer properly.

Comment: OK, I might not be able to til after a few days though. Thanks for your time!